# icacls : create private directory (full control for user and no listing for others except admins)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, icacls

I would like to create a folder with permissions similar to my home directory. I tried giving myself full control etc. but I managed to get locked out and had to use the takedown tool to be able to delete the directory.

I know Deny permissions take precedence over Allow but that's about it. This is for Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/inheritance:r` to remove all the inherited ACEs and `/grant` to add in the permissions you want the directory to have.  You can do this in a single command, like:

```
icacls test /inheritance:r /grant me:(OI)(CI)(F) /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Do **not** use the `/deny` option.  There are rare cases where deny entries are useful, but this isn't one of them.